# SharePoint 2010 New Installation - Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I just finished a new installation of SP 2010 and created my first Site Collection using Web App http://sp2010/ (Site collection URL - didn't append anything to URL)

When I navigate to this URL: http://sp2010/ ---> I get "404 Not Found"

Thanks for the help
Regards

Comment: has anyone found an answer to this question? I am currently expieriencing the same behaviour. Sorry for posting in the answers section but i cannot post comments...

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the Site Collection List in Central Admin, make sure your site is listed there. If it is, if you haven't been able to make use of the site yet, delete & recreate the site collection. If the same result, and this is the only site collection on the web app, delete & recreate the web app as well.

Were there any errors on install? What install method did you use (Setup Wizard, Config Wizard, and Farm Configuration Wizard, Powershell scripted install)?